# problems connecting to wireless network when installing lubuntu

Tags: installation, wireless, lubuntu

I would like to install lubuntu on my LG netbook.  I previously ran Ubuntu 10.04 and yesterday installed Ubuntu 12.10 but found it too slow.

During the install I get the screen that shows I am not connected to the internet.  Behind it I see a notification that I am not connected to the internet.

My question is can I use the terminal emulator to manually connect to my wireless internet or is there a way to show my network connections and choose the one to connect to (this is what the 12.10 install did and it worked for me)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to connect to a wireless network by either manually writing the necessary configuration file, or using the `wpa_cli` command line tool. Both of these options are explained in some more detail by this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/341102/how-to-connect-to-a-wifi-from-command-line-under-ubuntu-without-conf-file). Neither is easy or pretty, I'm afraid.

I'm not sure why this is necessary though - the install should finish quite happily without an internet connection, and you can then set up the connection using the `NetworkManager` GUI from the desktop once the install is done.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  You helped solve my problem and more.  Both comments were helpful.  I am glad to know how to manually configure a wireless network (or at least better understand what is involved in doing it).  But I followed your suggestion to go through the install without internet and everything worked great - I just wasn't aware I could install without the internet.